# Semi transparent bitmap overlay renders wrong colour

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I have a stack of bitmaps that I need to render one above the other. I achieve this with a relative layout and several ImageViews on top of each other which all have a Bitmap assigned to it.

This works great, but when the top layers is semi-transparent, the colours of the lower bitmap are off.

All my bitmaps use `Config.ARGB_8888`.

Say the top layer is red with an alpha of 50% and the bottom layer is green with an alpha of 100%.

I can either set the colour of the bitmap to red, then the alpha of the ImageView to 0.5f and it will render the green colour below fine (darker green with some red mixed in).

If I set the bitmap pixels to a 50% red like this: `bmp.eraseColor(0x7Fff0000);` and leave the imageView alpha on 100%, the green below will be displayed as yellow, mixing red and green, rather than overlaying it.

Unfortunately I can not use the (working) fist version because the alpha on the Bitmap above is not going to be uniform.

Is there a blend mode setting to use true colours when using semi transparent pixels in a Bitmap?

EDIT: I have also tried to set several PorterDuffXfermodes to the ImageViews but none gives the right result.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY)); //OVERLAY//ADD//SCREEN//DARKEN//LIGHTEN
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, needed to premultiply the alpha to get the desired result.